# Notifee on iOS - Dismiss, Clear doesn't fire off onBackgroundEvent?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

have anyone implemented Notifee recently on iOS with onBackgroundEvent? I was trying to get it work but the event fires off only on Android. This issue seems to be related to iOS, the same application works as expected on Android.

I also used their Example app from their Github to reproduce the issue.

When notification is displayed and app is `inactive` or `background` then `notifee.onBackgroundEvent` doesn't fire off. Events from `onForegroundEvent` like `Press` are detected.

Is it a bug or it requires something else in addition to what is in their docs?

React 18.2
React-native 0.73.1
Notifee 7.8.0 and 7.8.2

This is the Example app from Notifee which I've tested https://github.com/notifee/notifee/tree/master/packages/react-native/example

I also tried bare minumum version, still doesn't work. No log in console and also doesn't clear Badge count.

```
notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
  const { notification, pressAction } = detail;
  if (type === EventType.PRESS) {
    console.log("App opened from click");
    await notifee.setBadgeCount(0).then(() => console.log('Badge count removed'));
  }
  // Check if the user pressed the "Mark as read" action
  if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && pressAction.id === 'mark-as-read') {
    console.log('Background notification mark as read by user', detail.notification);
    await notifee.setBadgeCount(0).then(() => console.log('Badge count removed'));
  }

  if (type === EventType.DISMISSED) {
    console.log('Background notification dismissed by user', detail.notification);
    await notifee.setBadgeCount(0).then(() => console.log('Badge count removed'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information of your code for know where is the error, another think is try to figure out if you execute notifee.onBackgroundEvent immediately when the app is initiated